# Postfix catch all for emails which include a unique id

Tags: postfix

I would like to allow email addresses that have an unique id as prefix.
For example U123456_bla@bla.tld and U654321_bla@bla.tld would be accepted and send to one users email box.

Postfix works fine on my box and I tried to add to my main.cf

```
recipient_canonical_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/recipient_canonical-regexp
```

and defined in `/etc/postfix/recipient_canonical-regexp`

```
/\wbla@bla.tld$/        myuser
```

But I had no luck with it. How can this be done?
Any help very very appreciated
Thanks in advance
Jens

Answer (score 3):

I would do it using a virtual map, not a recipient_canonical map.  Try that, along with a pattern like:

/.*foo@example.com/    foo

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried your suggestion in my virtual alias map and still the emails were rejected. However after I used your regexp in my /etc/postfix/recipient_canonical-regexp it wokred out fine.

Thanks again and have a nice day
Jens

Answer (score 0):

I know it's possible to use a suffix after the username with Postfix and an MDA like Procmail - this is how my ticketing system does email-to-ticket. But I don't remember the exact setup.

I'd look around for Address Extensions in the Postfix docs. I have a feeling you can only use a suffix, not a prefix.

Comment: I think you're thinking of "recipient_delimiter". According to the docs it only allows suffixing. Setting recipient_delimiter to "-" would let you use the form bla-U123456@bla.tld

Comment: Oops. Yeah, that's what I meant...